# Wait until key is released

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to make it so my program doesn't continue before ALT is released so I can toggle my bool without infinitely cycling through my if(istrue/isfalse) .

This is my attempt at doing that

```
        for (;;) {
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_MENU))
    {
        TPSWITCH = !TPSWITCH;   
    }
    else
    {
        continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question??

Comment: what a strange code 1) you have no way to go out of your _for_, 2) you do an active wait, 3) the _continue_ is useless

Comment: after your edit this is still strange, still no way to go out of the _for_ and the `else continue;` is useless ... as probably the flip flop on _TPSWITCH_

Comment: @bruno for the context of my program the for loop always has to be running. How could i make it so the bool toggles only once when the key is pressed

Comment: @HangUp I said because you speak about _without infinitely cycling_. Out of that I do not see any link with the _my program doesn't continue before ALT is released_. So, why do you put the current code in these conditions ?

Comment: What problem are you *really* trying to solve? What subsystem are you targeting (WINDOWS/CONSOLE/...)? What's the specific reason to use `GetAsyncKeyState`?

Comment: @bruno it cycles trough my if(istrue/isfalse) in the background because the bool toggles on and off without stopping.

Comment: Subsystem is critic here. Please provide that info.

Comment: @IInspectable I'm quite new to c++ so it is the only way I know how to detect keypresses

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm sorry what?

Comment: Windows subsystem or console subsystem. Which is it?

Comment: Its not a console program so i guess windows.

Comment: Not sure where you are headed with this code, but for human activity, you probably do not need to 'poll' any faster than 10 hz.  I suggest you replace "continue" with "std::this_thread::sleep_for(100ms);"  This will dramatically reduce the cpu activity.

Comment: I suggest you review the function `WaitForSingleObject`.  IMHO, sleeping for an event to occur is the best use of computer resources.  Another idea is to have the OS send your program a message when the key is released (processing message loop / event handler).

Comment: @2785528 I'm trying to make it so when the key is pressed once the code gets executed once,

Comment: You should read about GetAsyncKeyState() from MS.   Your code ignores that more than one state idea is returned from that function.  For instance, part of the return tells you that the key is up (or down) ... which sounds like what you want.

Answer (score 0):

[`GetAsyncKeyState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate) checks the status of the key. When you hold down the ALT key, it returns to the down state every time, so `TPSWITCH = !TPSWITCH` is executed every time you go into the loop. Try the following code to wait until the key is up:

```
for(;;)
{
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_MENU)&0x8000)  //0x8000 ignore the least significant bit
    {
        while (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_MENU)&0x8000);
        TPSWITCH = !TPSWITCH;
        cout << "key up" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        continue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically the output returned by GetAsyncKeyState(...) is at a lower level than what you want, if what you are interested in is a semantically rich user action such as a "click". GetAsyncKeyState(...) literally just tells you whether a key is up or down at that moment -- this is not what you want to loop on because running computer programs are running over lots and lots of discrete moments.

What you need to do is "parse" these state changes into the user actions you want via a simple state machine. Something like the following will work. I included a boolean for running a message loop in there because if you try using this in a GUI application the whole application will freeze while it is waiting for a key. Add in the message loop as an excercise. Extend this to support double clicks as another excercise.

```
class KeyListener
{
private:

    enum class State {
        Preclick,
        ClickInProgress,
        ClickComplete
    };

    int vkey_;
    State state_;

    bool isDown() const
    {
        return GetAsyncKeyState(vkey_) & 0x8000;
    }

    State UpdateState()
    {
        switch (state_) {
            case State::Preclick:
                state_ = (isDown()) ? State::ClickInProgress : State::Preclick;
                break;
            case State::ClickInProgress:
                state_ = (isDown()) ? State::ClickInProgress : State::ClickComplete;
                break;
            case State::ClickComplete:
                state_ = (isDown()) ? State::ClickInProgress : State::Preclick;
                break;
        }
        return state_;
    }

public:
    KeyListener(int vkey) : vkey_(vkey)
    {
        Reset();
    }

    void Reset()
    {
        state_ = (!isDown()) ? State::Preclick : State::ClickInProgress;
    }

    void WaitForClick(bool pump_messages = false)
    {
        while (UpdateState() != State::ClickComplete)
            if (pump_messages) {
                // .. put a message loop here.
            }
    }
};

int main()
{
    KeyListener clicky(VK_SPACE);
    std::cout << "Try clicking the space bar" << std::endl;
    while (true)
    {
        clicky.WaitForClick();
        std::cout << "<Space bar click>" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```